# How to add an information page?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new in Android programming and I need some help.
I'm doing an app for my thesis and I need at the first access(installation) to have an information page(like Google Calendar when recently installed). And the user will be able to go on pressing on a "Next" button.
This "page" must be visible only if the application is removed and after a while reinstalled.
Can someone help me to handle this?

Comment: I doubt you'll find much help for such a general query -- it sounds like you're looking for a tutorial on basic android app building, to start -- and StackOverflow actually has a pre-canned response for these kind of questions: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Also just FYI, if by "first access" you mean when the user first opens your app, this could be at a different time than installation.

Comment: Thank you for the informations. I didn't ask for a book or something similar to a tutorial.  The simply reason why I asked here is because I've heard about this website and I though that guys with much more experience can help me to do something useful and well done.
Sorry for my English, it's not my forte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this.  One of them would be to take advantage of the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in Android.  Make a default value of false.  When your app starts, check the value in the shared preference that you set.  If it is false, show the information dialog and then set it to true.  If the value is true, continue with application startup.  SharedPreferences will be deleted when you uninstall the application, so your information dialog will be shown again if the user uninstalls and then re-installs your app.

[Here are some examples of using SharedPreferences.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store some kind of flag for this, for example you could use SharedPreferences and store a key called "firstLaunch" with a default value of true. At startup read the flag, show info if it's true, and set to false.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 
I have understood what do you mean, but could you show or send me a link with an example with this implementation?

Comment: Not really. Is there something in particular you're wondering about. If you've ever written an app and/or have read the most fundamental developer guides this should be straightforward. What did you try so far?

Comment: It's my first app. While I'm developing it, I follow an online course the I've bought some time ago, other tutorials on youtube or webpages and I searched something on stack overflow.
Until now I have done a first activity(let's call it MainActivity) which is called every time the app runs. Also I have done an another activity which shows up after the user presses "Next" button in the first activity.
This second activity must send an SMS to a phone number(specified by user) containing a string.

Comment: Now what I'm trying to do is to save somehow the phone number and to skip these 2 activities until the app is not reinstalled.

Comment: If all you've done is followed a bunch of tutorials, I *strongly* encourage you to familiarize yourself with http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html. Both read the beginner guides and learn how to search for stuff, such as SharedPreferences which I told you about. In addition to the actual class reference, there is a guide specifically for how to use SharedPreferences at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref.

Comment: Regarding your newly mentioned additions about storing phone numbers etc, well you could use the same approach there, but this seems like a different question. If you keep adding more questions as comments in the same question this page will be messy. Try the things out that I told you about, and if you get concrete issues or questions, raise them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Showcase View](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) to visualize the most important functions of your app.

> The ShowcaseView (SCV) library is designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

You could use that to develop your information page.